# Killing a System Process

Tags: asp.net, apache, networking

When I am trying to run Apache, it does not run. It tries to access the port 80 but port 80 is listening by a system process having PID 4.

How I can stop the "system" process?

Comment: Oh my...so many tags that have nothing to do with the question.

Comment: I am assuming you are on windows (since you have tagged this with asp.net)? Or are you on Linux or some other system?

Answer (score 1):

Windows provides an excellent tool called Resource-Monitor (resmon.exe). On the network tab, it gives you a detailed view of what programs are listening on what ports on you computer. Just open that tool to find out the program currently listening on port-80 (whether its IIS or something else). Then all you have to do is end that process and remove it from your startup in case it is sitting there.

Answer (score 0):

Port 80 is by default used by IIS. If you are running IIS on your machine, then you can stop it as explained [here](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/95826e7a-bac4-4e1f-bcb6-c52d49c9d7f4.mspx?mfr=true).

Answer (score 0):

Skype also use port 80, so you may turn off skype and reload your apache server.